# Parse JSON String into JSONArray (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

i'm trying to parse a json string to a JSONArray element, but when i try i get "cannot be converted to JSONArray"

My string is this way (but way longer):

```
{
"mylist": {
    "myinfo": {
        "user_id": 6225804,
        "user_name": "culo",
        "user_watching": 1092,
        "user_completed": 0,
        "user_onhold": 0,
        "user_dropped": 0,
        "user_plantowatch": 0,
        "user_days_spent_watching": 0
    },
    "anime": [{
        "series_animedb_id": 1,
        "series_title": "Cowboy Bebop",
        "series_synonyms": "; Cowboy Bebop",
        "series_type": 1,
        "series_episodes": 26,
        "series_status": 2,
        "series_start": "1998-04-03",
        "series_end": "1999-04-24",
        "series_image": "https:\/\/myanimelist.cdn-dena.com\/images\/anime\/4\/19644.webp",
        "my_id": 0,
        "my_watched_episodes": 0,
        "my_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "my_finish_date": "0000-00-00",
        "my_score": 0,
        "my_status": 1,
        "my_rewatching": 0,
        "my_rewatching_ep": 0,
        "my_last_updated": 1493924579,
        "my_tags": ""
    }, {
        "series_animedb_id": 5,
        "series_title": "Cowboy Bebop: Tengoku no Tobira",
        "series_synonyms": "Cowboy Bebop: Knockin' on Heaven's Door; Cowboy Bebop: The Movie",
        "series_type": 3,
        "series_episodes": 1,
        "series_status": 2,
        "series_start": "2001-09-01",
        "series_end": "2001-09-01",
        "series_image": "https:\/\/myanimelist.cdn-dena.com\/images\/anime\/6\/14331.webp",
        "my_id": 0,
        "my_watched_episodes": 0,
        "my_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "my_finish_date": "0000-00-00",
        "my_score": 0,
        "my_status": 1,
        "my_rewatching": 0,
        "my_rewatching_ep": 0,
        "my_last_updated": 1496668154,
        "my_tags": ""
    }, {
        "series_animedb_id": 6,
        "series_title": "Trigun",
        "series_synonyms": "; Trigun",
        "series_type": 1,
        "series_episodes": 26,
        "series_status": 2,
        "series_start": "1998-04-01",
        "series_end": "1998-09-30",
        "series_image": "https:\/\/myanimelist.cdn-dena.com\/images\/anime\/7\/20310.webp",
        "my_id": 0,
        "my_watched_episodes": 0,
        "my_start_date": "0000-00-00",
        "my_finish_date": "0000-00-00",
        "my_score": 0,
        "my_status": 1,
        "my_rewatching": 0,
        "my_rewatching_ep": 0,
        "my_last_updated": 1496668441,
        "my_tags": ""
    }, ETCETERA 1000 more like this one
```

I don't really care about the "mylist" or "myinfo" part, just the "anime" part is needed. There are about 1000 items.

I've validated my JSON and it is valid.

This is my code:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(replacedString);
JSONArray replacedResponse = new JSONArray(replacedString);
```

and here is where my issue begins. I've also tried this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(replacedString);
JSONArray replacedResponse = object.getJSONArray("mylist");
```

and
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(replacedString);
    JSONArray replacedResponse = object.getJSONArray("anime");

with similar results

What i'm I not seeing here? thanks in advance!

Comment: mylist is not an array, its an object with myinfo (object) and anime(array),... try http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to get the right pojo

Comment: i've tried also with this:     
    JSONArray replacedResponse = object.getJSONArray("anime");
it throws : org.json.JSONException: No value for anime

Comment: than it should result in something like `object -> getJsonObject(mylist) -> getJsonArray(anime)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this code.

```
    String stringObj = "[YOUR JSON]";

    // first Convert string into JsonObject
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringObj);

        // Inside the above object you have "mylist" key and the respective JsonObject so
        JSONObject myListObject = jsonObject.optJSONObject("mylist");

        // Insdide mylist you have myinfo Json and anim JsonArray
        if(myListObject == null) {
            return;
        }

        JSONObject myinfoObject = myListObject.optJSONObject("myinfo");
        JSONArray animeJsonArray = myListObject.optJSONArray("anime");

        // check null for myinfoObject and animeJsonArray and do the operation

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i am a simple man. I understand the explanation. I copy, paste and modify my own code. It works. I mark the answer as correct.